# Map one array to another in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to map one array on to another and if they match then display the value from the second

Here is my code;

```
let carMakes = ["ford", "volvo", "tesla", "BMW"];

let carMakeStrings = {
  ford: "Ford Motor Company",
  volvo: "Volvo Cars",
  tesla: "S3XY",
  BMW: "BMW",
  GM: "General Motors",
  Jaguar: "Jaguar",
  AlfaRomeo: "Fiat Chrysler Automobiles"
}

return (
    <div>
        <ul>
            {carMakes.map((carMake, key) => {
                return (
                    <li
                        key={key}
                    >
                        {carMake === carMakeStrings ? (carMakeStrings.value):("")}
                    </li>)
            })}
        </ul>
    </div>
)
```

What I want to display is an unordered list of 4 items like this

- Ford Motor Company
- Volvo Cars
- S3XY
- BMW

Currently I think I'm completely off with this solution but I'm not sure what to research - if someone can at least point me in the correct direction of what I should be researching that would be very appreciated

Comment: Are the `carMakes` entries guaranteed to be present in the `carMakeStrings` array?

Answer (score 2):

You can check with this condition `carMakeStrings[carMake]` to check whether it exists or not:

```
return (
    <div>
        <ul>
            {carMakes.map((carMake, key) => {
                return carMakeStrings[carMake] && (
                    <li key={key}>
                        {carMakeStrings[carMake]}
                    </li>)
            })}
        </ul>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use bracket notation to look up the `carMake` property on the object:

```js
const App = () => {
  let carMakes = ["ford", "volvo", "tesla", "BMW"];

  let carMakeStrings = {
    ford: "Ford Motor Company",
    volvo: "Volvo Cars",
    tesla: "S3XY",
    BMW: "BMW",
    GM: "General Motors",
    Jaguar: "Jaguar",
    AlfaRomeo: "Fiat Chrysler Automobiles"
  }

  return (
      <div>
          <ul>
              {carMakes.map((carMake, key) => (<li key={key}>{carMakeStrings[carMake]}</li>))}
          </ul>
      </div>
  )
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```